# django template print only first unique occurance

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a pretty simple task to do but I do not know how to do it most effectively in django templates.
Basically, this is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Jan. 27, 2015
    first post
    second post
    third post
Jan. 28, 2015
    another post
    and other
    etc
Feb. 18, 2015
    again
    and again
```

This could be its model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField()
    name=models.CharField()
```

In views.py passing just queryset as posts:

```
Post.objects.filter(date__gte = date.today()).order_by("date")
```

And then in template priting it out with for cycle:

```
{% for post in posts%}
    {{post.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I get printed unique date only once? Is it possible to do this in templates or do I have to take care of it in views? I found similar two year old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501876/displaying-unique-objects-only-in-django-templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [{% ifchanged %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% ifchanged %}<h3>{{ post.date }}</h3>{% endifchanged %}
    <div>{{ post.name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [inbuilt template tag for that - `regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup)!

This isn't perfect, but with the documentation it should get you close.

```
{% regroup posts by date as date_list %}

<ul>
{% for date in date_list %}
    <li>{{ date.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in date.list %}
          <li>{{ date.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I find catavaran's answer easier, but thanks for your answer as well! I should have think of going through template build in tags earlier.